# How to solve TypeError issue with the msg.sender in the constructor of a transaction service provider smart contract that doesn't allow for compiling

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am currently writing a smart contract and I am not able to compile due to an error on owner = msg.sender. I am also using ^0.8.0 . I would like to know what issue has to be resolved for the smart contract to be able to compile. I had tried adding the address function to the owner variable to make the msg.sender into an address payable. I still got the same error.

```
contract ServicePay{
    address payable public owner;
    address payable public buyer;
    address payable public seller;
    uint public amount;
    bool public resolved;
    uint public expiration;
    uint public fee;

    constructor(address payable _buyer, address payable _seller, uint _amount, uint _expiration) {
        owner = msg.sender; //Where the error is
        buyer = _buyer;
        seller = _seller;
        amount = _amount;
        resolved = false;
        expiration = _expiration;
        fee = _amount * 2 / 100;
    }

    

    function release() public {
        require(!resolved, "The payment has already been resolved.");
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can release the funds.");
        seller.transfer(amount - fee);
        owner.transfer(fee);
        resolved = true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this is a **question** and answer site. You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Got it, thank you. It has just been Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `owner` property is of type `address payable` (extension of type `address`).

Since Solidity v0.8.0, `msg.sender` is only of type `address` (not the `payable` extension).

You can convert `address` to `address payable`:

```
// within the constructor
owner = payable(msg.sender);
```